# Harmonizing Monero with HD Wallet BIP 39 Technology?

Tags: wallet-recovery, privatekey

Monero currently uses [Electrum Word List](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/tree/master/lib/wordlist) for recovery purposes.  This causes conflicts with wallet developers that want to support both Bitcoin-based [BIP 39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) technology that has a separate [Word Lists](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/bip-0039-wordlists.md). End users will want to use only one set wallet recovery words. Here is a Lingua Franca Rosetta translation approach so wallet developers can give end users the option of going either directions.

`% echo "artwork crowd need rent install fire draw escape moment myth strong belt chair quiz cinnamon lab park leopard bicycle empty harvest cream matter teach" | bx mnemonic-to-seed -p 123 | bx hd-new -v 61143388 | bx hd-to-ec`
**a41ebdce18ffcbad14e8d0313b14017884fd51e2344e0353242cb686a00a588e**

`% echo "artwork crowd need rent install fire draw escape moment myth strong belt chair quiz cinnamon lab park leopard bicycle empty harvest cream matter teach" | bx mnemonic-to-seed -p 123 | bx hd-new -v 61143388`
**msec6JS8ftS7w7Ca2w8Kesn3xpDSto9rdAefrWoJ9NchAv6ub7AGQBLQZZGbSPxt6SbAzTAncGn8gQKMGuDnNMmohNLodVhwnaLsyNbqTeeaAQw**

`% ./mnemonics a41ebdce18ffcbad14e8d0313b14017884fd51e2344e0353242cb686a00a588e`
**dyslexic buffet veteran tamper racetrack hefty joking negative sedan initiate vague hounded dewdrop governing ecstatic skulls nabbing tumbling pledge long aided jetting reorder evaluate reorder**

If https://xmr.llcoins.net/ is used to encrypt the Electrum seed words above with the password “123”, the following encrypted recovery Electrum seed words result:

**syndrome koala daytime tuition tufts yanks unafraid meant fuming inorganic drowning rudely affair emit coils refer tiger dynamite selfish galaxy aunt eclipse tunnel poker inorganic** (These words can later be decrypted with the password of 123)

The following will then become Monero's private spend key from which a stealth address can be calculated:

`% ./sc_reduce32 a41ebdce18ffcbad14e8d0313b14017884fd51e2344e0353242cb686a00a588e`
**3c7f0ee745e638ed6101141a464509d183fd51e2344e0353242cb686a00a580e**

**Does it make sense to recognize this BIP 39 synthesis approach as a legitimate means to synthesize stealth addresses that supports interoperability with Electrum's recovery words?**

*Note the dependence upon [BIP 32 Harmonization](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/harmonizing-monero-with-hd-wallet-bip32-technology) with the EXT_SECRET_KEY assumed to be 61143388.*

Comment: Trezor and libbitcoin provide BIP 32/39/44 seed portability between each other, see https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/issues/380.  Beware of https://medium.com/@alexberegszaszi/why-do-my-bip32-wallets-disagree-6f3254cc5846#.du1v0n47x.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does make sense for Monero to support BIP 39 words used by traditional HD hardware wallets such as [Trezor](http://satoshilabs.com/trezor/), Keepkey or Ledger.

We will see how much the https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2495/experimental-trezor-firmware-testing distribution for tailored Monero Trezor firmware, a forked simplewallet, and a forked trezorctl command will support the recommendations above.

Specifically, the **trezorctl recover_mnemonic** command line is the use case for converting BIP 39 seed words provided by a Trezor device and converts them to Electrum seed words for wallet recovery outside a Trezor hardware wallet.

For more information, see [With Monero firmware loaded on a Trezor, how does one create private spend keys from the BIP 39 seed words supplied during a Trezor's configuration?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/with-monero-firmware-loaded-on-a-trezor-how-does-one-create-private-spend-keys) that also desires to push the envelope for having Monero provide nominal BIP 44 support.