# How does one convert the Trezor seed to a simplewallet seed and vice versa

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, trezor, mnemonic-seed

Now that the source is available I thought I'd bring up the subject of the seed difference between the Trezor and Simplewallet. The Trezor uses 24 words, while Simplewallet uses 24 plus an extra word as a checksum. How compatible are these two seeds? And what needs to be done to convert a simplewallet seed to a Trezor so that people don't need to "sweep" funds to a brand new seed, as well as doing the reverse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the experimental binaries, which can be found [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2495/experimental-trezor-firmware-testing), NoodleDoodle included a tool called `trezorctl`. With this tool you can convert your Trezor mnemonic seed to a mnemonic seed compatible with simplewallet. Thus, using this tool allows you to, after conversion, restore your wallet using simplewallet. The tool works as follows. Note that `<word_list>` is your 24 word Trezor mnemonic seed. On Linux and Mac OS:

`./trezorctl recover_mnemonic <index> <passphrase> <language> <word_list>`

On Windows make sure to launch it from the command line. Go to the folder monero-cli-wallet is located and make sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files. Subsequently do SHIFT + right click and it will give you an option to "Open command window here". Lastly, type the following command:

`trezorctl.exe recover_mnemonic <index> <passphrase> <language> <word_list>`

The default language is English for seeds. Note that simplewallet also supports Spanish, German, Italian, Japanese, Russian, and Portugese. Lastly, the trezorctrl output looks like this:

```
USAGE: trezorctl recover_mnemonic index passphrase language word_list
            Supported languages:
            English
            Spanish
            German
            Italian
            Portuguese
            Russian
            Japanese
```

Comment: It should be noted that the <index> should start at 0.

Comment: So it looks like the [production trezorctl](https://github.com/trezor/python-trezor/blob/master/trezorctl#L336) and the **forked trezorctl** commands are very different. Thus, **recovery_device** is solely meant for BIP 39 recovery words and **recover_mnemonic** is solely meant for Electrum recovery words.  What about taking this to the next level for achieving interoperability between BIP 32/39/44 & Electrum words? [see]( http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/harmonizing-monero-with-hd-wallet-bip-39-technology)

Comment: The corresponding simplewallet takes a corresponding **index:addr_version**,  will/could/should addr_version impact the behavior of the command above?

Answer (score 5):

I've never owned Trezor so my answer might be irrelevant, but I've studied the code to learn how the Electrum seed phrase is treated in the simplewallet so that I can create my own specific choice of seed phrase.

From lines 216-221 of [electrum-words.cpp](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/mnemonics/electrum-words.cpp), with `seed_length` being set constant to 24, I guess the number of words in the phrase can be either 12, 24, or 25. Line 224 suggests that the 25th word if existent would be treated as a checksum.

So, if Trezor gives you 24 words, I guess you can just put those 24 words (i.e. with no checksum) into simplewallet to restore your wallet. Hope this works.

Comment: The [English Electrum Seed Word List](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/mnemonics/english.h#L54) and the [English BIP 39 Seed Word List](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) are of different lengths and the words they contain are very different.

Comment: It's been almost 4 years since this was answered. Has anyone actually gone through the BIP39 seedphrase => Monero "Electrum" seedphrase conversion?