# If you create a Bitcoin wallet with Trezor first, could you use the private key to create a Monero wallet using NoodleDoodle's firmware?

Tags: privatekey, hardware-wallet, trezor

I just received my Trezor and I wanted to go ahead and send some Bitcoin's to it while I figure out how to work the Monero Trezor firmware by NoodleDoodle. Is it possible to import the private keys I create with the main Trezor firmware now with the Monero Trezor firmware I install at a later time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one convert the Trezor seed to a simplewallet seed and vice versa](http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/how-does-one-convert-the-trezor-seed-to-a-simplewallet-seed-and-vice-versa)

Comment: I guess my question is more geared towards the firm ware. If I installed the main firmware on my Trezor that generates a private key, could I use that same Trezor to install the Monero version or would I need to use a completely new Trezor? I know the two seeds are compatible, but I figured since you installed something completely new on there it would wipe out any trace of what was on there before.. (?)

Comment: @floam412 I suggested an edit to clarify your question and remove the part about the firmware guide. Can you make that into a second question?

Comment: @seekadventure yeah, right now I'm about to step into work though. I will once I get home... Sorry for the terrible wording of the question lol.

Comment: I think with the recovery procedure you can use the seed used for bitcoin for your Monero.. But it is not ideal because it might be hard to do so without exposing your seed..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing a new firmware on a Trezor, it won't be possible to import private keys.

Because of the way Hierarchical Deterministic wallets work, a new seed and wallet will be created (with its own set of private keys).

Therefore, you should temporarily transfer your bitcoin to another safe offline device while you set up the new firmware and seed and make sure you have back ups for the temporary wallet.