# If I use the trezor beta and something goes wrong, can I recover my coins with the seed?

Tags: monerod, wallet-recovery, trezor

If I knew that I could always recover my money with my seed, then I wouldn't be afraid to try out the trezor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can always recover your money with the 24 word seed. If your Trezor somehow gets broken, you can get a new one and import the "old" 24 word seed into the new one.

Alternatively, if the firmware somehow becomes incompatible, you can convert your Trezor 24 word seed to a 25 word seed compatible with `monero-wallet-cli` using [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/how-does-one-convert-the-trezor-seed-to-a-simplewallet-seed-and-vice-versa/1658?noredirect=1#comment941_1658) guide. Thus, after conversion, you'd be able to restore your coins with the `monero-wallet-cli` using the following command:

Linux and Mac OS X

`./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet`

This should be done from the terminal from the directory of `monero-wallet-cli` itself.

Windows:

`monero-wallet-cli.exe --restore-deterministic-wallet`

This should be done from the command window from the directory of `monero-wallet-cli` itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the BIP39 seedphrase => Monero "Electrum" seedphrase conversion? They use different dictionaries, no?

Comment: Yes, they use different dictionaries (and by extension, seed standards). Hence, it needs to be converted in order to be restored 'normally' in the Monero software.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The [guide you linked to](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/how-does-one-convert-the-trezor-seed-to-a-simplewallet-seed-and-vice-versa/1658?noredirect=1#comment941_1658) doesn't seem to be a conversion process really but rather @kenshi84 guessing that it might work without conversion based on number of words.  Now that we know they are different dictionaries, this doesn't seem possible.  Am I missing something?

Comment: NoodleDoodle's tool actually converted the Trezor 24 word mnemonic seed to a generic / standard 25 word Monero mnemonic seed. Thus, it is definitely possible to transform the seed. Unfortunately, I don't think the code was ever published / open-sourced.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (I was looking at the answer below yours). Seems [NoodleDoodle's tool](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2495/experimental-trezor-firmware-testing) has been deleted from GitHub and Mega and the official `trezorctl` [hasn't implemented](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/blob/master/python/src/trezorlib/cli/monero.py) such a seed phrase conversion tool unfortunatly.  Guess I'll keep researching.