# Clarification on the Monero Trezor binaries 'passphrase'

Tags: hardware-wallet, trezor

I presume that the 'passphrase' in the Monero Trezor binaries [mentioned here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/how-does-one-convert-the-trezor-seed-to-a-simplewallet-seed-and-vice-versa), is the same thing as the Trezor passphrase [mentioned here](http://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/advanced_settings.html#multi-passphrase-encryption-hidden-volumes)? Just want to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Based on this seed, does anyone know the bip44 path that Trezor/Monero uses?  i.e. 44'/128'/0' this is my guess but it doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also agree, it is the same. Adding a password makes a new private seed different from the 12 or 24 word base seed.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct as far as I know.